# Image preview and remove with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, preview

i have problem about coding image preview in jquery.

I want to show to users multichosed image before upload my server. And one that Cancel buton on every image. if this buton click, photo on will remove from preview.

When clicked save buton, save all preview image to my server.

I need it, pls help me :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#images').on('change',function(e){
            var files=e.target.files;
            $.each(files, function(i,file){
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                reader.onload = function(e){
                    var preDiv=document.querySelector("#imgs ul");
                    var template="<li class='col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6'><img src='"+e.target.result+"'/><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove cancel'></span></li>";
                    preDiv.innerHTML+=template;
                };
            });
        });



        $(".cancel").click(function(){
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: You need help, we need information. Can you please share with us what you have tried so far and where your specific problem lies? Have a look at [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [On-Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: ok sorry, i'am new here. Now i load my tried

Answer (score 1):

Solved problem.

added span element onclick method in this line:

```
var template="<li class='col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6'><img src='"+e.target.result+"'/><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove cancel' onclick='imgRemove(this)'></span></li>";
```

and created this method:

```
function imgRemove(ths)
            {
                $(ths).parent().remove();
            }
```